# Zcoin insight setup in ubuntu system

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I have tried to installed zcoin insight ui & api in my local machine (ubuntu OS) and it is completed all the steps but I m facing issue while start services in frontground.

Let me share with you command, config file.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config libssl-dev libevent-dev bsdmainutils
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt install libminiupnpc-dev
sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev
sudo apt-get install libqrencode-dev
git clone https://github.com/zcoinofficial/zcoin.git
cd zcoin
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
cd src
./zcoind
```

But getting below error in my terminal:

```
   [2018-02-07T14:05:58.941Z] info: Starting bitcoin process
zcoind: zmq/zmqpublishnotifier.cpp:99: virtual void CZMQAbstractPublishNotifier::Shutdown(): Assertion `psocket' failed.
[2018-02-07T14:05:59.837Z] warn: Bitcoin process unexpectedly exited with code: null
[2018-02-07T14:05:59.837Z] warn: Restarting bitcoin child process in 5000ms
[2018-02-07T14:06:04.837Z] info: Using bitcoin config file: /home/zcoincore/bitcore-node-zcoin/zcoinnode/data/zcoin.conf
[2018-02-07T14:06:04.838Z] info: Starting bitcoin process
[2018-02-07T14:06:04.847Z] error: Failed to start services
```

### MY Config File  (zcash-bitcore-node.json)

```
    {
  "network": "testnet",
  "port": 3004,
  "services": [
    "bitcoind",
    "insight-api-zcoin",
    "insight-ui-zcoin",
    "web"
  ],
  "servicesConfig": {
    "bitcoind": {
      "spawn": {
        "datadir": "./data",
        "exec": "/home/zcoincore/zcoin/src/zcoind"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Zcash Config  (zcash.conf)

```
server=1
whitelist=127.0.0.1
txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=YANNISCOOLUSER
rpcpassword=YANNPASSISCOOL
uacomment=bitcore
```

Can you please help me with it? What is wrong in which step?

Comment: Your problem is with `zmqpubrawtx`

    zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
    zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332

Remove them and see if it will work.

Comment: Hello @Adam,
Thanks for your feedback but it is getting below error after remove this 2 line from zcash.conf.

error: Failed to start services
error: Invalid state: "zmqpubrawtx" option is required to get event updates from bitcoind. Please add "zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:<port>" to your configuration and restart

Comment: Hello @Adam,

Working fine after change 127.0.0.1 to MyserverIpAddress.

Comment: Hello @Adam,

In dash currency, I did same thing but it is returning error.

Warning: Failed to create backup, file already exists! This could happen if you restarted wallet in less than 60 seconds. You can continue if you are ok with this.
dashd: zmq/zmqpublishnotifier.cpp:101: virtual void CZMQAbstractPublishNotifier::Shutdown(): Assertion `psocket' failed.

Comment: please add another question with more details

Comment: @Adam: Added another question: please https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70483/dashcoin-insight-setup-in-ubuntu-system help me about it.

Comment: I stuck in blocks api & send api. I have setup in my server http://159.89.175.64:3004/insight/blocks but not able to get all block. This  url, I am not getting Amount: http://159.89.175.64:3004/insight/block/4b62193f2c4d93a945dce08e185e1842222230e4e233077070cde47b74683e5b
API, I installed it from here: https://github.com/Technoprenerd/insight-api-zcoin But still not working

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue,

Actually it was issue related confliction because I have setup more than one currency in single server Like (Bitcoin, litecoin & zcash)

For that, I have taken care rpcport & change port for "zmq" in config file and then it is working fine.

Config:

```
server=1
whitelist=127.0.0.1
txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28334
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28334
rpcport=8334
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=YANNISCOOLUSER
rpcpassword=YANNPASSISCOOL
uacomment=bitcore
listen=0
```