# DashCoin insight setup in ubuntu system

Tags: bitcoind, bitcore, dash

I have tried to installed dash insight ui & api in my local machine (ubuntu OS) and it is completed all the steps but I m facing issue while start services in frontground.

Let me share with you command, config file.

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcore-dash`

But getting below error in my terminal:

`[2018-02-09T04:18:18.022Z] info: Using config: /home/dashcore/.bitcore/bitcore-node-dash.json
[2018-02-09T04:18:18.024Z] info: Using network: testnet
[2018-02-09T04:18:18.026Z] info: Starting bitcoind
[2018-02-09T04:18:18.028Z] info: Using bitcoin config file: /home/dashcore/.bitcore/data/dash.conf
[2018-02-09T04:18:18.030Z] info: Starting dash process
dashd: zmq/zmqpublishnotifier.cpp:101: virtual void CZMQAbstractPublishNotifier::Shutdown(): Assertion psocket' failed.
[2018-02-09T04:18:18.245Z] warn: Dash process unexpectedly exited with code: null
[2018-02-09T04:18:18.246Z] warn: Restarting dash child process in 5000ms
[2018-02-09T04:18:23.247Z] info: Using bitcoin config file: /home/dashcore/.bitcore/data/dash.conf
[2018-02-09T04:18:23.248Z] info: Starting dash process
dashd: zmq/zmqpublishnotifier.cpp:101: virtual void CZMQAbstractPublishNotifier::Shutdown(): Assertionpsocket' failed.
[2018-02-09T04:18:23.481Z] warn: Dash process unexpectedly exited with code: null
Warning: Failed to create backup, file already exists! This could happen if you restarted wallet in less than 60 seconds. You can continue if you are ok with this.`

### MY Config File  (bitcore-node-dash.json)

`{
  "network": "testnet",
  "port": 3006,
  "services": [
    "bitcoind",
    "web"
  ],
  "servicesConfig": {
    "bitcoind": {
      "spawn": {
        "datadir": "/home/dashcore/.bitcore/data",
        "exec": "/home/dashcore/.bitcore/data/dashd"
      }
    }
  }
}`

### Dash Config  (dash.conf)

`server=1
whitelist=127.0.0.1
txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://MyIPAddress:28332
zmqpubrawtxlock=tcp://MyIPAddress:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://MyIPAddress:28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=dash
rpcpassword=local321
uacomment=bitcore`

Can you please help me with it? What is wrong in which step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration. It worked for me it might work for you too.

```
server=1
whitelist=0.0.0.0/0
txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtxlock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
rpcuser=dash
rpcpassword=local321
rpcport=9998
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
uacomment=bitcore
debug=0
testnet=1
```